# mapping new ns to old ns + Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools : flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, sdk

i started flutter today
if i want run my app i get this error:

> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 30s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        43.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

please help